# How can I do a For in ASP.Net Webforms that adds elements with the <asp> tag in each iteration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my .aspx file, I am trying to add List Items within a Dropdown, through a script that contains a For, but I don't know how to correctly add these items.
I did a test example to simplify the problem, with numbers from 1 to 10, so you can understand a little better the problem I am having

I tried this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="numbers" runat="server">
    <script runat="server">
        void loop() {
            for(int i=1; i<1=10; i++) {
                <asp:ListItem>i</asp:ListItem>
            }
        }
    </script>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

the error given says "the name asp does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Don't put code like this in the aspx file. It belongs in the code behind file : .aspx.cs . Better still if you have pretty much any collection you can data bind it to the item.

Comment: write code in aspx.cs file or use asp:repeater to bind listitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in you code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
                numbers.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```